# fs.readFileSync cannot find file when deploying with lambda

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In my code I am calling a query from my lambda function

```
let featured_json_data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data/jsons/featured.json'))
```

This works locally because my featured.json is in the directory that I am reading from. However when I deploy with serverless, the zip it generates doesn't have those files, I get a

`ENOENT: no such file directory, open...`

I tried packaging by adding

```
package: 
include: 
 - data/jsons/featured.json
```

but it just doesn't work. The only way I get this to work is manually adding the json file and then change my complied handler.js code to read from the json file in the root directory.

In this screenshot I have to add the jsons then manually upload it again and in the compiled handler.js code change the directory to exclude the data/jsons

[image]

I want to actually handle this in my servereless.yml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load JSON files using `require()`.

```
const featured_json_data = require('./featured.json')
```

Or better yet, convert your JSON into JS!

Comment: thanks, let me test. Just to clarify, do i have to specify the path of the json file or will require know where to find it?

Comment: `require` requires you to provide the relative path to the JSON file in the same way you `require` JS files.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked! Didn't realize thats how the rest of my javascript files are being found and could apply it to json files.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at `copy-webpack-plugin`: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

You can use it to package other files to include with your Lambda deployment.

In my project, I had a bunch of files in a /templates directory. In webpack.config.js to package up these templates, for me it looks like:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      './templates/*'
    ])
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

For working with non-JSON files, I found that `process.cwd()` works for me in most cases. For example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

export default async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    console.log('cwd path', process.cwd());

    const html = fs.readFileSync(
      path.resolve(process.cwd(), './html/index.html'),
      'utf-8'
    );

    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
      },
      body: html
    };

    callback(null, response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> fs.readFileSync cannot find file when deploying with lambda

Check the current directory and check target directory content in deploy environment. Add appropriate code for that checking to your program/script.

Comment: Can you look at my updated screenshot. The problem is when I deploy with servereless it doesn't include my directories, it compresses all the js files in handler.js and since my json files are static i have to manually add them and zip them back. I want to be able to include them in my deployment.

Comment: Thanks will add you!